# Semantics of `async for` - can __anext__ calls overlap?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

If `__anext__` gives control back to event loop (via an `await`, or `call_soon`/`call_later`), is it possible for another `__anext__` to be called on the same instance, while first one had not resolved yet, or they would be queued? Are there any other cases where it would be unsafe to assume that only one `__anext__` is running at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer:** Using `async for` does not overlap, but calling `__anext__` does.

**Long answer:**

Here is what I made while playing with `__anext__` mechanics:

```
import asyncio

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = 0

    def __aiter__(self):
        return self

    def __anext__(self):
        def later():
            try:
                print(f'later: called when state={self.state}')

                self.state += 1
                if self.state == 3:
                    future.set_exception(StopAsyncIteration())
                else:
                    future.set_result(self.state)
            finally:
                print(f'later: left when state={self.state}')

        print(f'__anext__: called when state={self.state}')
        try:
            future = asyncio.Future()

            loop.call_later(0.1, later)

            return future
        finally:
            print(f'__anext__: left when state={self.state}')

async def main():
    print('==== async for ====')
    foo = Foo()
    async for x in foo:
        print('>', x)

    print('==== __anext__() ====')
    foo = Foo()
    a = foo.__anext__()
    b = foo.__anext__()
    c = foo.__anext__()
    print('>', await a)
    print('>', await b)
    print('>', await c)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*asyncio.Task.all_tasks()))
loop.close()
```

I had implemented `__anext__` to return future instead of just being `async def`, so I have better control of intermediate steps of resolving these futures.

Here is an output:

```
==== async for ====
__anext__: called when state=0
__anext__: left when state=0
later: called when state=0
later: left when state=1
> 1
__anext__: called when state=1
__anext__: left when state=1
later: called when state=1
later: left when state=2
> 2
__anext__: called when state=2
__anext__: left when state=2
later: called when state=2
later: left when state=3
==== __anext__() ====
__anext__: called when state=0
__anext__: left when state=0
__anext__: called when state=0
__anext__: left when state=0
__anext__: called when state=0
__anext__: left when state=0
later: called when state=0
later: left when state=1
later: called when state=1
later: left when state=2
later: called when state=2
later: left when state=3
> 1
> 2
~~~ dies with StopAsyncIteration ~~~
```

In `async for` case it can be seen that `__anext__` completes first, then event loop kicks in and runs whatever was scheduled with a delay. If `__anext__`s were stacking, event loop would take this opportunity to schedule another `__anext__` call until delayed `later` would start - instead, event loop blocks until it's `later`'s time to run.

So, if your async iterator is only to be used in `async for`, it's safe to assume that there would be only one `__anext__` running at the same time.

With `__anext__` it's worse: you can stack them up as much as you'd like. However, this shouldn't be of much concern, if your `__anext__` is coroutine - it shouldn't keep any state when invoked anyway. Or at least I think so.

Comment: As worded, your answer is no responsive to the original question.  The question talks about awaiting within the anext.  I think what you do is isomorphic to that, but your answer would be significantly better if you reworded to help the reader be convinced of that.

Answer (score 2):

Now that we have [asynchronous generators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/), I wondered what the answer to this question was for concurrent calls to `__anext__()` when the implementation is provided by an asynchronous generator. I tried the following test program:

```
import itertools
import trio

async def foo():
  for i in itertools.count():
    await trio.sleep(1)
    yield i

async def go(aiter):
  return (await aiter.__anext__())

async def amain():
  aiter = foo().__aiter__()
  async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
    nursery.start_soon(go, aiter)
    nursery.start_soon(go, aiter)

trio.run(amain)
```

This fails with:

```
RuntimeError: anext(): asynchronous generator is already running
```

As far as I can tell, this comes from CPython and not trio. So in CPython at least, I believe that concurrent calls to the `__anext__()` created automatically from an asynchronous generator are checked for and not permitted. Presumably it is up to the caller to make sure this doesn't happen.

I haven't been able to find a definitive specification that says that the behaviour must be like this, so perhaps this shouldn't be relied upon. Ensuring that the caller never does this seems to be the reliable bet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible to executed multiple `__anext__` tasks simultaneously. As with any other generator, every call to `__anext__` will execute until first `yield` (`await` is `yield from`).

Whether this is safe or unsafe depends on the implementation:

1. Implementation that enforces order via queue or other synchronization primitive will be safe
2. Implementation whose `__anext__` uses internal state should be safe, but order of the results will undefined
3. Implementation that modifies shared state will be unsafe